# T-SQL SELECT Statement to return records using Conditional Operators

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, conditional-statements

I'm using SSMS 17.9.1 - I have a table with a `ContractNo` and `RightCodes` columns. See image attachment for sample data:

[image: SampleData]

I need a `SELECT` statement that will return rows where `RightsCodes LIKE '904'` or '908', but where there are no other rows with the same `ContractNo` that have `RightCodes LIKE '922'` or '923' or '924'.

So in the example data I would expect Rows 1 and 8 to be returned.

There can be x number of rows that have the same `ContractNo`. And `RightCodes` can have 1 to x number of values per `ContractNo`

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make some data (noting the terrible way to store data):

```
DECLARE @bad_table TABLE (
    [row] INT,
    contractno INT,
    rightcodes VARCHAR(512));
INSERT INTO @bad_table SELECT 1, 28205, '904,908';
INSERT INTO @bad_table SELECT 2, 28205, '911,913';
INSERT INTO @bad_table SELECT 3, 28194, '904';
INSERT INTO @bad_table SELECT 4, 28194, '923,924';
INSERT INTO @bad_table SELECT 5, 28194, '922';
INSERT INTO @bad_table SELECT 6, 28192, '908,923';
INSERT INTO @bad_table SELECT 7, 28192, '911';
INSERT INTO @bad_table SELECT 8, 28193, '904';
```

Write a query to pull out the data as required:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    @bad_table b
WHERE
    (b.rightcodes LIKE '%904%' OR b.rightcodes LIKE '%908%')
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @bad_table xb WHERE xb.contractno = b.contractno AND (xb.rightcodes LIKE '%922%' OR xb.rightcodes LIKE '%923%'));
```

This gives the results you want, rows 1 and 8.

Comment: Although it doesn't appear to be an issue with the extensive sample data provided, this method of matching substrings embraces a significant issue. If it used used to check for `'23'` it will find it in `'23'`, `'123,456'`, `'12321'`, ... . An alternative is to use `',' + EvilListColumn + ',' like '%,' + @TargetValue + ',%'` to ensure that the value found is delimited by commas. Another alternative is to use [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and compare the separated values in a set-based manner.

Comment: @HABO - Thanks for pointing this out. In this case the values range from 904 - 972 so I don't foresee this as being an issue.